# Pulling Data from Django database

Tags: python, django, kendo-ui

I am doing the basic Django polls tutorial and am placing the polls results into Kendo graphs. I Currently have a bar, donut, and bubble chart showing the results for the selected poll question. I want to add a line chart, but instead of using just the results from the selected poll, to also include data from the other questions. Is there a way of doing this, for I am unable to find the answer. I have placed my current code below.

```
# Javascript in results.html
$("#chart4").kendoChart({
  legend: {
    position: "bottom"
  },
  seriesDefaults: {
    type: "line"
  },
  series: [
    # Don't know what to do here
    { 
      name: ?
      data: ?
    }
  ],
  valueAxis: {
    labels: {
      format: "{0}%"
    }
  },
  categoryAxis: {
    categories: [{% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}"{{answer.choice_text}}", {% endfor %}]
  }
});
```

views.py

```
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('id')
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_position = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for doing that is querying Django through Ajax. You must define a view that return some data (preferably json) and then call it from your js script.

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse

def all_questions(request):
    """
    Most of the time you will have to do some extra work formating the json in 
    order to match the format  that the JS library is expecting.

    I can see your graph is expecting something like:

        series: [{  
                name: <some_sustom_name>
                data: <array of values>
            }
        ], 


    So you need to provide to the JS library the data it is expecting. 
    That means some array (or perhaps similar data structure). 

    """

    questions = Questions.objects.all()
    response = serializers.serialize('json', questions)

    # Now response contain a representation of a 
    # json object that has a property called data
    # besides, that property contain a list of Django objects.
    response = "{data: %s}" % response    

    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")
```

*For more info about the content of `response` see: [Serializing Django Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/serialization/)*

Now, lets assume you got the data in your javascript (the Ajax call was successfull) you will have something like:

`{data: [list of serialized Django objects]}`

You just have to process list above and extract the data for your graph. Of course you can obtain that list directly from the Django view . That's your call.

See this [Kendo demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/bar-charts/index.html) for more info on what to put  in `series` section of graphs.

**Querying Django through Ajax from JQuery**.

For this you need code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",                    // 1
    url:"url_to/you_view",          // 2
    data: {                         // 3
        'zip': zip,             
    },
    success: function(data){        // 4    

    },
    error: function(error){         // 5
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

**1** - Specification of the request method (GET, POST, UPDATE, etc ....)

**2** - The url pointing to your view.
    Note that there are any protocol specification (http). As your js lives in your django app
    the url is relative to this app. For this you need some url like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('your_app.views', 
    ...
    url(r'url_to/you_view', 'your_view')
    ...
)
```

**3** - Optional, some data to send to de django view. (in your case you don't need it)

**4** - This is important, here you will process the data returned by the server when the request success. 
    Following the example above data here is a json object like:

`{data: [...]}`

where `[...]` stands for a list of django serialized objects with jason format.(See the links for documentation).

**5** - On `error` this function will be called instead of that specified by `success`.

For more info on $.ajax object from JQuery see the [$.ajax API Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Could you please explain how i would implement this view into my javascript in the results.html file. I am having a little trouble understanding.

Comment: Or how I could successfully call the data from the Django view using ajax

Comment: Ok, I update the answer with some tips on how to query a Django server from ajax(using JQuery). I hope this help.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I do have one more question. Which Django serialized object would work for [...]. Sorry, I am very new to Django.

Comment: Note `{data: [...]}` would be in the javascrit, that part isn't Django any more. In the first code sample I show you how to serialize a django query set. You can serialize any django object/queryset.

If my answer did help you, please upvote me :D

Comment: I gave you an up-vote, as your help is much appreciated. I am unclear how to implement the view `all_questions` into my `results.html` file, I am very unclear of this process. Thanks again :D

Comment: Also, how would I call this in my `$(#chart4)` section of Javascript?